# Integral of Laplacian on complete non-compact manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, laplacian

Let $(M,g)$ be a complete non-compact manifold,  $\Delta$ denote the Laplacian operator on smooth functions.

**Q** Is this true that $\int_M(\Delta f\cdot f)dvol_M\geq0$  for any function $f\in L^2(M)$ or $L^2_1(M)$.

Here $\Delta=d^*d$, I think it is not true for smooth case, e.g. $f=\exp(x)$ on $\mathbb R$.

I think it is true for $f\in L^2_2$, as $\Delta:L^2_2\to L^2$ is a continuous operator.

Comment: Assuming your sign convention is $\Delta=(d+d^*)^2$, yes.

Comment: @user10354138 How about $f=\exp(x)$ on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Remember the minus sign coming from $\Delta=d^*d=-\operatorname{div}\circ\operatorname{grad}$, and also, $\exp\notin L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes, so I add $f\in L^2/L^2_1$. Sorry, I did not figure out why it is true?

Comment: $L^2_1\subset L^2$ as a vector subspace, so $\exp\notin L^2_1$ either.

Comment: @user10354138 I agree with you, so we need the  assumption  that $f\in L^2/ L^2_1$.

Comment: @user10354138 could you give a proof or some reference ?

Comment: By definition, $L^2_1=\{f\in L^2\mid Df\in L^2\}$

Comment: Are $L^2_1$ and $L^2_2$ meant to be Sobolev spaces? And what do you mean by $\Delta f\cdot f$ for $f\in L^2$? The Laplacian of an $L^2$ function is a distribution in $H^{-2}$.